# resize fancybox when I click the fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I use fancybox for my website to enlarge my pictures. What I want is to make a sort of zoom function.

When the fancybox is open and I click on the image in the fancybox I want to increase the width of the fancybox

I tried something like

**Markup:**

```
<div style="display:none;">
<div id="view_invoice" style="height:950px; width:663px;">
    <div class="process"><img src="../../images/progress.gif" /></div>
    <div id="showInvoice" style="position:absolute;"></div>
</div></div><a id="get_invoice" href="#view_invoice" style="display:none;">link</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.table_content_results table').click(function()
{
    $('#showInvoice').html('');
    var invoiceDir = $(this).attr('dir');
    var invoiceId = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/get_pdf.php",
        data: "INVOICE_ID="+invoiceDir,
        complete: function(data)
        {
            $('#showInvoice').html(data.responseText);
        }
    });

    $("#get_invoice").fancybox(
    {
        'overlayOpacity'    : 0.6,
        'overlayColor'      : '#000',
        'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
        'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
        'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
        'easingIn'          : 'swing',
        'padding'           : 10,
        'autoDimensions'    : true
    }
    ).trigger('click');
});

$("#showInvoice").click(function()
{
    $("#view_invoice").animate({ width: 1000 });
    $("#showInvoice").width(1000);
    $("#showInvoice").children('img').animate({ width: 1000 });
    $('#fancybox-wrap').width(1000);
    $.fancybox.center();
});
```

This works but not properly. The size of the fancybox increase but the position is not at the center of my screen so i tried to fix that with $.fancybox.center(); but that didnt work.

The second thing is that the div where the image is in dont increase width so I get some scrollbars. I tried to fix that with $("#showInvoice").width(1000); but I still get the scrollbars instead of a div with a width of 1000px.

So I hope that someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try resizing the window after all.

```
$(window).resize();
```